# For-each loop is iterating backwards

Tags: java, foreach

Given the code

```
String[] p = { "A", "B", "C", "D" }; 
String b = ""; 

for ( String q : p ) 
   b = q + b; 

System.out.println( b );
```

I thought the output would be "ABCD" but it is "DCBA"

Why??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your loop *prepends* each element to `b`.
That is:

- prepend "A" -> "A"
- prepend "B" -> "BA"
- prepend "C" -> "CBA"
- prepend "D" -> "DCBA"

If you want to get "ABCD", change the logic to *append*:

```
for ( String q : p ) {
   // b = q + b;  // prepend
   // b = b + q;  // append
   b += q;        // append, using the shorter `+=` notation
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because in

```
b = q + b;
```

- `q` represents current element loop is getting from your array
- `b` is result of previous concatenations

which means you are adding *new part* in front of old result.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
q + b;
```

means `new element + old string`.

For each iteration through the 4 element array, the values are

```
b = "A" + "" - resulting in "A"
b = "B" + "A" - resulting in "BA"
b = "C" + "BA" - resulting in "CBA"
b = "D" + "CBA" - resulting in "DCBA"
```

Change the assignment to 
    b = b + q;
or
    b += q;